# Is there a way to typecast void pointers in Lauterbach

Tags: debugging, trace32, lauterbach

I have a structure containing a void pointer but when I need to view the contents of this pointer, I want it to be displayed as a pointer of a particular type. Is there a means to do this within Lauterbach? I tried using the symbol.AddInfo.Type command but it doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a cast operator directly in the watch window.

E.g.: `Var.AddWatch (struct struct1 *)pLinkedListBuf`

[image]